# How is backgrounding a process implemented in terms of Linux system calls?

Tags: linux, bash, system-calls, background-process

How is backgrounding a process (for example, in Bash) implemented in terms of Linux system calls?

---

The purpose of my question is that I don't understand why bash manual says

> asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment,

(if I am correct, "aynchronous commands" means running the commands in background), 
while, by using `strace`, I found that the parent shell process first calls   `clone()` to create a subshell which is a copy of itself, and then the subshell calls a `execve()` to replace the subshell itself with the command to run in background.

This is just like running a foreground process.  I don't see the command is invoked in the subshell. 
If I am correct, invoking a command in subshell means the subshell invokes  `clone()` to create a subsubshell, and then the subsubshell invokes  `execve()` to replace the subsubshell itself with the command to run in background. But in reality, the subshell doesn't call `clone()`.

For example,

In Ubuntu, I run `date` in an interactive bash shell whose pid is 6913, and at the same time, trace the bash shell from another interactive bash shell by `strace`.

When running `date`, the output of tracing the first shell 6913 in the second shell is :

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
[sudo] password for t: 
Process 6913 attached
clone(Process 12918 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 12918
[pid  6913] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 12918] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
[pid 12918] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ff00c632740) = 0
[pid 12918] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 12918] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 12918
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12918, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6781518, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

When running `date &`, the output of tracing the first shell 6913 in the second shell is :

```
$ sudo strace -f -e trace=process -p 6913
Process 6913 attached
clone(Process 12931 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f457c05ca10) = 12931
[pid 12931] execve("/bin/date", ["date"], [/* 66 vars */]) = 0
[pid 12931] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f530c5ee740) = 0
[pid 12931] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 12931] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12931, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 12931
wait4(-1, 0x7ffea6780718, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
```

Answer (score 1):

> the subshell doesn't call clone()

This is an explicit optimization. bash realizes that there is no point in doing another costly fork if the subshell's only job is to execute a single external command synchronously. From [execute_cmd.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n1538):

```
/* If this is a simple command, tell execute_disk_command that it
     might be able to get away without forking and simply exec.
     This means things like ( sleep 10 ) will only cause one fork.
     If we're timing the command or inverting its return value, however,
     we cannot do this optimization. */
```

The only real syscall difference between `date` and `date &` is therefore that the latter isn't followed by a `wait`.

The more interesting case that the bash manual alludes to is when you run non-external commands. The difference between `let i++` and `let i++ &` is that the former is evaluated by the bash itself, while the latter is evaluated by a subshell which then exits, and therefore has no effect.

Comment: The glibc `fork` function does _not_ use the `fork` syscall [anymore]. The function is a [somewhat elaborate] wrapper around the `clone` syscall. `bash` can call `clone` directly if it wishes. But, either way, the setup [overhead] is the same. The `fork` function does `clone` with an option that says it want a separate address space, but `pthread_create` calls `clone` with an option saying it wants a shared address space

Comment: Perhaps you mean, "if the subshell's only job is to execute an internal command synchronously" (and that internal command doesn't manipulate state).

Comment: `clone` [nee `fork`] is actually quite lightweight. It does _not_ make a copy of the parent's memory. It sets up the child page tables to match the parent [relatively fast]. For any writable page in the parent, the PTB entry is marked R/O in both parent and child. When one of them writes to a given page, a page fault occurs, and the process is then given a private copy of the shared page and the PTB's of both are adjusted [to R/W]. This is "fork on demand" or "copy-on-write". So, if a child only hits a page or two before doing `execve`, the overhead is quite low.

Comment: Thanks @that! "This is an optimization." Do you have some reference to back up this statement? (What I want to know the most is whether my understanding of "invoking a command in a subshell" is correct or not. if your statement is true, then the subshell should indeed invoke clone to create a subsubshell, which doesn't happen due to optimization)

Answer (score 1):

The text *"asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment"* doesn't specifically refer to backgrounding, because backgrounding is an interactive concept from "POSIX job control". Whereas asynchronous commands occur interactively or non-interactively.

*"Invoked in a subshell environment"* is just shell terminology which means that a `fork` takes place, and these commands run in a child process which cannot modify variables in the parent and other state:

```
$ VAR=value &
[1] 15479
[1]+  Done                    VAR=value
$ echo $VAR
$
```

Because the variable assignment is run in a subshell, it has no effect in the parent shell.

How backgrounding works in terms of system calls is that POSIX job control revolves around a set of processes which are organized into process groups, which belong to a session, which is attached to a controlling terminal.  Only one group at a time in a session is the *foreground process group*.

The reason the design revolves around groups rather than individual processes is because jobs consist of multiple processes when piping is used. For instance, `sort -u file | grep foo` creates a process group with two processes.

The shell itself is also in a process group. When the shell is prompting you for input, that process group is in the foreground. When the shell executes a job in the foreground, it places itself into the background with some special job control system calls.

When you send a Ctrl-Z to the TTY, it generates a `SIGTSTP` signal to every process in the foreground process group. The shell detects this change in child status (via `waitpid` or some such) and then shuffles that group to the background, putting itself to the foreground again, to receive TTY input.

When you're talking to the shell, all jobs are in the background, whether they are running or not: the shell is the foreground process group, so all the other jobs are not. With the `bg` command, you are just changing the running state of a suspended background job. Ctrl-Z sent a `SIGTSTP` which suspended it, and the shell moved it to the background. `bg` will resume it, allowing it to execute. However, if a background job is resumed and tries to obtain input from the TTY, it gets a `SIGTTIN` signal and is suspended again:

```
$ cat &
[1] 12620
$ bg
[1]+ cat &
$     # hit Enter 
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
$ bg
[1]+ cat &
$     # hit Enter
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
```

`cat` wants to read from the tty, so when we put it in the background, it gets a `SIGTTIN` from the kernel's TTY subsystem which stops it. The shell detects this signal-driven change in status similarly to Ctrl-Z/`SIGTSTP` and prints a message telling us that the job stopped. Every time we `bg` it (resume it) the same thing happens. The shell dispatches `cat` (probably with a `SIGCONT`), and `cat` immediately resumes trying to get input from the TTY which responds with "you're not a member of the foreground process group, bad kitty: `SIGTTIN` for you". All this whole time, `cat` never leaves the background.

Comment: "backgrounding" is not a job control concept. We called it that back in the Bourne shell days, before job control was invented (original it was in `csh` in BSD).